# Directory group permissions trouble on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit and have created a group 'dcc' to which I added myself as user 'ralc'. After logging out and back in again I tried the command 'groups' and it gives me the line:

```
ralc adm ... dcc
```

(some groups omitted)

I then created a directory 'dccdir', used `chmod g=rwx dccdir; chmod u= dccdir` and changed the directory group with `chgrp dcc dccdir`. The result from `ls -l | grep dcc` is as follows:

```
d---rwxr-x  2 ralc dcc 4096 2011-04-26 18:56 dccdir
```

Now for the real question: seeing that I'm in the same group as the directory, I would assume that I should be able to access and list the contents of the directory. However, when doing `ls dccdir` I get the message:

```
bash: cd: dccdir/: Permission denied
```

Can you explain where I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you own the directory, only the "owner" permission bits are applied. "Group" and "world" permissions are ignored.

Quote manual page [`path_resolution(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html):

> #### Permissions
>
> The  permission  bits  of a file consist of three groups of three bits,
>   cf. [chmod(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/chmod.1.html) and [stat(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html). **The first group of three is used when the
>   effective user ID of the calling process equals the owner ID of the
>   file.** The second group of three is used when the group ID of the file
>   either equals the effective group ID of the calling process, or is one
>   of the supplementary group IDs of the calling process (as set by
>   [setgroups(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setgroups.2.html)). When neither holds, the third group is used.